# Help removing class with checkbox

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove a class from a div with a checked checkbox

My Jquery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
// Submit form when checkbox is pressed
  $(function() {
$('.menuitem input:checkbox').change(function(){
    $('form').submit();
    })
// Remove hidediv class from div - DOES NOT WORK
    $('input:submit').hide().addClass("sdasd");
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('div.hidediv').removeClass("hidediv").show(slow);
    } else {
        $('div.hidediv').addClass("hidediv");
    }
});
});
  </script>
```

My CSS:

```
.hidediv {display:none;}
```

My HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>

        <div class="menuitem">
        <label for="search_company1">company1</label>

        <input name="search[company1_is_true]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="search_company1_is_true" name="search[company1_is_true]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        </div>
        <div class="menuitem">
        <label for="search_company3">company3</label>
        <input name="search[company3_is_true]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="search_company3_is_true" name="search[company3_is_true]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        </div>
 <div class="hidediv">
        <div class="menuitem">
        <label for="search_company2">company2</label>
        <input name="search[company2_is_true]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="search_company2_is_true" name="search[company2_is_true]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <div>
</div>
    <input id="search_submit" name="commit" style="display:none;" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you submit the form on the button change and do nothing else:

```
$('.menuitem input:checkbox').change(function() {
    $('form').submit();
})
```

you should do:

```
$('.menuitem input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('div.hidediv').removeClass("hidediv").show('slow');
    } 
});
```

Ther is no point in putting an else like you did before if you take off the class, you can't use the class selector anymore like you did

Comment: It works, but just in the moment I have clicked the checkbox, the page reloads and it have forgot all about the checkbox is checked.

Comment: And the div does not have the slow animation

Comment: sorry i missed the quotes around 'slow'; of course your form is submitted, you should delete the first part (`$('.menuitem input:checkbox').change(function() {
    $('form').submit();
})`) Otherwise you always submit the form!

Comment: I want(need)  to always submit the form.

Comment: If you submit the form, you reload the page, and so you don't need to hide anything client side, but you should put your logic server side!

Comment: It is not possible to do anything server side and the page should reload every time a checkbox is changed.

Comment: Is it not possiable to make an ajax request when the form is submitted and the content the only content that is refreshed is the content in the div with the id of rightcontent?

Answer (score 0):

At the time that `if($(this).is(":checked")) {` is executed, `this` is not the checkbox. If you were to put this code within `$('.menuitem input:checkbox').change(function(){` then it would be, otherwise you will need to change it to:

```
if($(".menuitem input:checkbox").is(":checked")) {
```

I'm not sure what your intent is though.  As you have it now, the code is outside of the handler, meaning it will only run on initial load of the page.  If put within the handler it would run when the checkbox is checked or uncheck, however, you are submitting the form in the handler so that won't be much use.

You also have an extra `});` at the end.

EDIT:  After looking at it again, I found another isssue.  Using `show` will override the class you are using to hide your elements.  `show` is essentially an inline style which will override the class.  Instead, just use `show` and `hide` and abandon the class change (unless used for other styling).

EDIT2: You also have a broken div  `div>`.

Comment: Is it not possiable to make an ajax request when the form is submitted and the content the only content that is refreshed is the content in the div with the id of rightcontent?

Comment: It is possible to replace the regular form submission with an AJAX request, but you haven't done that.