# Rails Jquery - Metasearch page reload problem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using metasearch. I have created a form with checkboxes and each time a checkbox is changed the form is submitted and the page reloads.

The problem is that Jquery forget the state of the checkbox and some content that should appear is hidden.

See my Jquery code and html here: [Help removing class with checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901096/help-removing-class-with-checkbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with setting render :layout => false when the url got params and did make an ajax request instead and moved my menu to my layout file

Answer (score 0):

If the page reloads and you want to mantain the state (in this case, keep checkboxes clicked), you'll have to pass this info onto the next page.

jQuery is stateless, it doesn't keep or cache any info between requests.

Comment: In the action that processes this request, you should be able to access the checkboxes' state liks this: `@checkbox2 = params[:search]["company2_is_true"]`. Then, in the view, you use `@checkbox2` to determin whether the checkbox should be clicked or not. I'm not entirely sure i understood your question though...